# Link firebase user with in app subscription

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, in-app-subscription

In my app, I use Firebase authentication to get a user Id and save user related data in a backend server.
I have a also implemented an in-app subscription with google play store.

My issue is the following, a user log in with a twitter account and subscribe to the app. If he logout and sign in with facebook, it will be a new user in my backend. But the subscription will still be there as it is link to the google account of the phone.

In backend I will have two user with subscription active, but actually it is only one user.
How can I link this user in backend to have revelant information. (only one user with subscription active)

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: For the moment not so much, my user are well created on server but there is no link with the subscription. I'm looking for a unique subscription Id or something to save in backend and compare to see if it is same user. But apparently for same user orderId can be updated in each renewal...

Comment: There is no way to recognize user with the google account on the phone?

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: I'm considering just querying Google Purchases at the beginning of user login, and not even having subscribed status in the backend.

Comment: Same for me, didn't find any solution for the moment

Answer (score 0):

If the same user signs in with a different account, that means they've already purchased a subscription in your app. Your best approach sounds to link the two accounts from that user together, so that they can use the subscription no matter how they signed in. See the [Firebase documentation on linking accounts from different providers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking) for more information on this.

Comment: Yes but problem to link account, the user need to be log in with one account first, and then we are able to link a other provider...

Comment: That's indeed how it works. The logic is that when a user signs in, you check if they already signed in with that same email address and another provider. If so, tell them about that fact, have them reauthenticate with that other provider, and link the accounts.

Comment: What if a different user signs in that same device?  Say, user A signs in, and buys a subscription.  user A logs out, lends his phone to user B.  then user B logs in, and when there is a getQueryPurchases() and it returns true (because user A is stilled logged into Google Account), then user B would have his subscription status be marked true.

Answer (score 0):

With Native Play Billing Library 2.2+, you're able to tie the obfuscated app account id by calling setObfuscatedAccountId (and setObfuscatedProfileId if necessary) to the purchase when launching the purchase flow.
And you can retrieve this information on the purchase object.
You can link with the firebase UID encrypted for example.

> Many apps, particularly games, need to ensure that a purchase is correctly attributed to the in-game character/avatar or in-app user profile that initiated the purchase. Starting with Google Play Billing Library 2.2, your app can pass obfuscated account and profile identifiers to Google when launching the purchase dialog and have them returned when retrieving a purchase.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/developer-payload?hl=en#attribute